# Mirror flip animation

Tags: modeling, animation

I'd like to build the molecule shown on the top, where the three bonds form the legs of a tripod, and animate it's mirror flip to the one at the bottom. Appreciate suggestions on building the molecule as well as doing the flip. Ideally, at the mid-point of the flip animation, all three bonds would be coplanar. Many thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you use bones then duplicate the armature + object and flip on the axis you want (SX-1 for example) it seems to work fine, what difficulty do you meet exactly?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to build the molecule itself (with or without the spheres) where the angle between any two bonds is about 109 degrees. I was able to make it by creating a cylinder, duplicating, and rotating a couple of times. I then got stuck on animating this model where it flips over to its mirror image, kind of like an umbrella flipping inside out in a wind.